# How do I align saving a pdf file with the correct active worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to save a series of worksheets into individual files named for each Excel sheet.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets 
    fileName = RDB_Create_PDF(Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea), "N:\Excel\VBA\" & CleanStr(ws.Name) & ".pdf", True, True)
Next
```

. The problem is that the printarea and the filename change for each `ws` , but it saves only the information from the current active worksheet—i.e., I get the same worksheet information saved with different printarea ranges and different filenames. How would I get the active worksheet to align with the printarea and filename as the ws changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RDB_Create_PDF(Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea), _
               "N:\Excel\VBA\" & CleanStr(ws.Name) & ".pdf", True, True)
```

here `Range` will default to the ActiveSheet and not to `ws`

```
RDB_Create_PDF(ws.Range(ws.PageSetup.PrintArea), _
               "N:\Excel\VBA\" & CleanStr(ws.Name) & ".pdf", True, True)
```

is probably what you want but hard to tell for sure without posting the code for `RDB_Create_PDF`

Comment: The code for RDB_Create_PDF is too long to post. However, your suggestion seems to work, although all of the information on the original sheet is deleted after I run the sub.

Comment: That's likely happening somewhere in your called Sub

Comment: Here is a sample of the code (in the second grey box): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647945/solved-compile-on-demand-disabled

Comment: I think I figured it out. Myvar was set to = "".

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do I even really need RDB_Create_PDF?  Can I not do everything within the Sub?

Comment: No and Yes, although having the functionality as a separate procedure helps keep your code easier to follow.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for all your help.